# Norton's equivalent circuit - current through short circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, short-circuit, norton

In this tutorial, the tutor is finding current through 12 ohm resistor using Norton's theorem.

My question is:
When 12 ohm resistor was replaced with a short circuit, why entire current (15-I1) isn't flowing through the short circuit (AB)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the 12 ohm resistor is replaced with a short circuit then you would have no resistance and no voltage drop, but the current would flow.

You can make the circuit a bit simpler and remove/delete all the other resistors, because their resistance is much higher than the short circuit in the idealized model.

So you only have the short circuit and the two current sources.
If you write it now in a slightly other way, the two current sources behind each other, then you see two current paths.

Now you can calculate simply with the two current circles which are connected over the "short circuit".

10A is flowing in one direction and 15A in the opposite direction, so that the substitution of the current would be 5A or -5A depending how you look on it.

```
 |---------
 |        |
⬆10A      |
 |    5A  |
 |----=>---
 |        |
⬆15A      |
 |        |
 |---------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the answer. The Norton current is 5 ampere which you can also calculate like you said "why not all the current is flowing from the short circuit well if you calculate it. It will be 15-10 ampere which is equal to our Norton's current. You are saying the 18ohm resistor which is just beside of 12ohm will be short right but the 9ohm resistor will also be short and the current sources one which is upward direction and another one which is in downward direction will flow through the short circuit element.